# two instances of object with annotation @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need some help in Spring @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION). I'm creating web application and I have problem with session object. I created class:

```
@Component
@Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class FilterParameter {

    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> filters;

    public FilterParameter() {
        filters = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }

    public void addFilterParameter(String filterKey, String filterValue) {
        if (filters.containsKey("byKeyword")) {
            filters.remove("byKeyword");
        }
        filters.put(filterKey, filterValue);
    }

    public void addKeyWord(String filterValue) {
        if (!filters.isEmpty()) {
            filters.clear();
        }
        filters.put("byKeyword", filterValue);
    }

    public void removeFilterParameters(boolean allParam, String filterKey) {
        if (allParam) {
            filters.clear();
        } else {
            filters.remove(filterKey);
        }
    }

    public LinkedHashMap<String, String> getFiltersList() {
        return filters;
    }
}
```

I implemented it as a field in one of controllers.

```
@Controller
public class AssessmentController {

 private FilterParameter filterA;

  public AssessmentController(FilterParameter filterA){

        this.filterA = filterA;
  }

//...
}
```

And I need use it in another controller as a independent filter:

```
@Controller
public class ProcessController {

 private FilterParameter filterB;

  public ProcessController(FilterParameter filterB){

        this.filterB = filterB;
  }

//...
}
```

Spring create singleton FilterParameter for both controller. How can I set it to create independend instance of FilterParameter?

Comment: Everything doesn't need to be a bean and to be injected. This class isn't thread-safe, BTW, so, unless it's request-scoped, it shouldn't even be a field of your controllers. You probably just want to create a new instance in the *methods* that need one. But I have no idea of what this class is for and what you want to do with it.

Comment: How are you defining a bean based on **FilterParameter**?  Why aren't you showing that in your example?  Without that extra code, no injection would happen here.

Comment: How are you defining your **ApplicationContext**?  Session-scoped beans involve a **Session** object tied to an **ApplicationContext**.  If you've set all of that up correctly, you should be getting per-session beans injected into your Controllers. - It could be as simple as putting a **@Scope("session")** annotation on your **FilterParameter** class, but it can depend on other things.  Have you tried that?  You do that and still get singletons? I guess that's what you're implying, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Also, per-session doesn't mean per-Controller.  With a single Controller, Spring will wire in a different bean unique to each user/session using your site.  So if you're talking about the same user session utilizing both controllers, you'd want Spring to inject the same bean into both Controllers.  This, again, is why it's more a matter of how your (Web)Application context is set up, and what the details are of how your endpoints are getting called, that will determine which copies of beans get injected into your Controllers.

Comment: Here's a nice minimal example: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-mvc-session-scope.html

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot so I didn't define separate configuration class:
@SpringBootApplication
public class ForeignRegistrationApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ForeignRegistrationApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Comment: Purpose this filter (FilterParameter) is to filter array of assessment object (class Assessment) and array of process object (class Process). Each of these both object has its own controller. And these both object should has its own FilterParameter for filtering object.
HashMap (from FilterParameter) is used for creating dynamic SQL querry to obtain filtered list of these (Assessment and Process) object.